# Regex replace [eEzZ_ ] with a different string

Tags: regex

As immature as this is, the people on my server love saying "ez" which is a pretty big insult when it comes to playing the game my server hosts.  I tried writing a regex as follows to replace the text "ez" in their chat messages and various combinations but it failed miserably and misfired a LOT:

```
[eEzZ_ ]+
```

It misfires on things like "yes" or anything with a space in it.  I am trying to just replace the messages with segments containing ONLY e, z, space, and _ I guess this misfire with things like "bite zebra" probably....maybe there is some more clever way to prevent this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the regex I would use in your case:

`(?:e|E)[_\s\.]*?[zZ]+`

**Breakdown:**

1. Non-capture group allows us to alternate between a starting character of e or E `(?:e|E)`
2. We know the space or underscore will be in the middle, so place a repeating, lazy character class in there; just in case they omit that part. `[_\s\.]*?`
3. Finish off the expression by allowing an infinite amount of Z's `[zZ]+`

http://regex101.com/r/sQ8wW2

Comment: Well i'm concerned about things like "e z", "e_z", "_e z_" etc things to try and get around it.

Comment: Almost perfect.  I added "e" to the [_\s\.] and its perfect.  Thanks

Comment: What about words like accessorize? The expression in this answer would match the words breeze, bejeezus, freeze, and hezbollah

Comment: it can be wrapped in word boundary anchors `\b`

Answer (score 4):

What you have is a character class that matches one or more of any of e, E, z, Z, _, or space.  I think you may just want to do a case-insensitive match on `ez` or more accurately `\bez\b` (using word boundaries).  The underscore/space thing is not as clear to me.  Maybe `\be[_ ]*z\b`

Comment: Read my comment above in Vasili's answer.

Comment: @MasterGberry my pattern should match `e z`, `e_z`, and `ez`